# Custom Screen name validator's method not being called. Why?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I made a custom screen name validator in liferay 7 as given in the liferay-blade samples.But it's method validate() is not being called when adding a new user in liferay portal. Here is the CustomScreenNameValidator class:-

```
package com.liferay.blade.samples.screenname.validator.internal;

import com.liferay.blade.samples.screenname.validator.CustomScreenName;
import com.liferay.blade.samples.screenname.validator.CustomScreenNameConfiguration;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.PortalException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Log;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogFactoryUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.Company;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.module.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.module.configuration.ConfigurationProvider;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.security.auth.ScreenNameValidator;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.CompanyLocalService;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.settings.CompanyServiceSettingsLocator;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PropsKeys;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PropsUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.StringUtil;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;

/**
 * @author Romeo Sheshi
 */
@Component(
    configurationPid = "com.liferay.blade.samples.screenname.validator.CustomScreenNameConfiguration",
    immediate = true, property = {"service.ranking:Integer=100"},
    service = ScreenNameValidator.class
)
public class CustomScreenNameValidator implements ScreenNameValidator {

    @Override
    public String getAUIValidatorJS() {
        StringBuilder javascript = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            Company company = _companyLocalService.getCompanyByWebId(
                PropsUtil.get(PropsKeys.COMPANY_DEFAULT_WEB_ID));

            long companyId = company.getCompanyId();

            String[] reservedWords = _getReservedWords(companyId);

            javascript.append("function(val) { return !(");

            for (int i = 0; i < reservedWords.length; i++) {
                javascript.append(
                    "val.indexOf(\"" + reservedWords[i] + "\") !== -1");

                if ((reservedWords.length > 1) &&
                    (i < (reservedWords.length - 1))) {

                    javascript.append(" || ");
                }
            }

            javascript.append(")}");
        }
        catch (PortalException pe) {
        }

        return javascript.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription(Locale locale) {
        return "The screen name contains reserved words";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validate(long companyId, String screenName) {
        System.out.println("Hello from");
        String safeScreenName = StringUtil.toLowerCase(screenName);
        String[] reservedWords = _getReservedWords(companyId);

        for (String word : reservedWords) {
            if (safeScreenName.contains(StringUtil.toLowerCase(word))) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private CustomScreenNameConfiguration _getConfiguration(long companyId) {
        try {
            return _configurationProvider.getConfiguration(
                CustomScreenNameConfiguration.class,
                new CompanyServiceSettingsLocator(
                    companyId, CustomScreenName.SETTINGS_ID));
        }
        catch (ConfigurationException ce) {
            _log.error("Error initializing the configuration.");
        }

        return null;
    }

    private String[] _getReservedWords(long companyId) {
        CustomScreenNameConfiguration configuration = _getConfiguration(
            companyId);

        if (configuration != null) {
            return configuration.reservedWords();
        }

        return new String[0];
    }

    private static Log _log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(
        CustomScreenNameValidator.class);

    @Reference
    private volatile CompanyLocalService _companyLocalService;

    @Reference
    private volatile ConfigurationProvider _configurationProvider;

}
```

Is there any entry for the custom screen name validator class in any file in liferay? If so please tell me where to specify? If not, please specify what step might I have been missing? Please help....thanx in advance..

Comment: hi i contribute with this example and it was tested on liferay 7 ga3.  it works in edit user ? have you deploy other screennamevalidator plugin ? it seems a problem of ranking.

Comment: @Romeo: Thanks for your reply..It does not work in edit user. i did not deploy any other screennamevalidator plugin. Tell me what is the problem of ranking?

Comment: i have a problem with ranking when testing because i gave a number minor to other validators deployed in liferay so mine validator was ignored when i put a greater ranking it start working. Can you see if the configuration for the plugin is presente in system preferences?